# Can we write our own GUI instead of using kibana

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-5

In out project, we have decided to use ELK for the distributed logging mechanism. Our project has its own UI. We dont want to have 2 UIs. One for kibana and other for project.

So I would like to know,
1. if we can integrate kibana into our UI. 
2. After integrating kibana into UI, can we modify the look and feel.
3. Can we write our own UI which can pick data from elasticsearch.
Does Elasticsearch exposes APIs for the same.

Answer (score 3):

1) Yes, you can integrate kibana in your application, using iframe embedded dashboard.

2)Yes, you can modify the look and feel.
It's not easy but it's possible, we did it in our company("webiks"), and we have a lot of experience.

3)Yes. Elasticsearch expose API, so you can write your GUI alone, but in my opinion kibana did very good job so I think it's good tool to use.

Comment: Hi, Can you kindly elaborate on how you achieved point no 2? Thanks.